# SQL find users that consistently search with in five months during the whole year

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a SQL problem that I can't think a way to solve it.

Please check the below table.

[image]

I want to find users that search at least once within consistent 5 months

Can someone help me please?

Comment: what version of sql? Can you define *consistently search*? Is this once a month, or once a day, etc? Can you give a larger sample size and expected results

Comment: You need to tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: It is mysql I am so sorry

Comment: once a month but the user has to search at least once within consistent 5 months

Comment: in your sample you have not user  that match your criteria  .. had a proper data sample  in text mode (not image only) and the expected result  too

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)